# Why does QiSDK fail to resolve?

Tags: android-studio, pepper, nao-robot

I'm trying to make an application for SoftBank's robot Pepper using Android Studio, Java and QiSDK as recommended on their [website](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/starting_project.html#id1). After I create a robot application that adds the needed QiSDK dependencies to the project, those would not resolve after a gradle project sync. [Image of a warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKWla.png).

I tried to create a project on different devices, but got the same result. Is it maybe a problem that I am using a newer version of Android Studio 2021.3.1 Patch 1?

Comment: I downgraded to Android Studio 4.2.2 and it works fine. But I still don't know why it wouldn't work on a newer versions.

Comment: I admit I am surprised it makes a difference. The key issue is to get the maven repository configuration right, like in: https://github.com/aldebaran/qisdk-tutorials/blob/master/build.gradle#L28

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it's because you're missing a link to the repository in which qisdk can be found. You need to add this to your settings.gradle file, in the `dependencyResolutionManagement`'s section in `repositories`

```
     maven {
        url 'https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
    }
```

Mine looks like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, the Pepper plugin for Android Studio would edit the project's build.gradle to add this bit, but with newer versions of Android Studio, this repository config moved from the project's build.gradle to setting.gradle, so that line doesn't get updated any more, you need to add it manually.

Comment: Hi @Emile,
Are there any updates or workarounds to fix the emulator issues?
Perhaps with the Android plugin sources we can somehow provide a solution for the developer community.
And "use a real robot" is not a solution, knowing of ow much is slow uploads to the tablet.
Behind your product are companies with deadlines and customers to meet on schedule without having to waste man-days trying to "make things work" without any support from the manufacturer.
I trust that together we could find a solution, for us and many others.